# Join com criteria

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

Tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
public class Mapa {
   //many to one
   private ItemMapa itemMapa;
}

public class ItemMapa {
   //many to one
   private Classe classe;
}

public class Classe {
   private Long id;
}
```

Preciso implementar uma consulta utilizando `criteria`, porém não sei como fazer um join para chegar até o objeto `Classe` a partir do objeto `Mapa`. Em hql faria algo assim:

```
String hql = "FROM Mapa m WHERE m.itemMapa.classe.idClasse = :idClasse";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Mapa.class);
criteria.createAlias("itemMapa", "ITEM", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("ITEM.classe", "CLASSE" , JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("CLASSE.id", id));
Mapa mapa = (Mapa) executeCriteriaUniqueResult(criteria);
```